# PDF-documents not loading inside iframe in Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, kendo-ui, chromium

I want to display a given PDF-file inside the same browser window.
For this I fetch the base64-encoded file-data from the server and set the src-content.

```js
// mimeType usually is 'application/pdf'
iframeContent = `data:${fileBase64Data.mimeType};base64,${fileBase64Data.base64DataString}`;
```

```html
<iframe src="iFrameContent" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

Whenever I want to display a document in Firefox it displays the content just fine.
In Chrome or Edge it occasionally happens that the iframe doesn't get rendered at all. It just displays a blank space where the rendered document should be displayed.

Also I am using Kendo UI for jQuery with the MVVM-pattern as a framework. `src` instead looks like this: `src="#= data.iFrameContent #"`. But I am not completely sure if it has anything to do with my issue.

I've tested with a bunch of different files in pdf-format and the only pattern I could see was that the iframe stops rendering if the size of the file exceeds roughly 6MB.
I tried to display it via `<embed>` as well but it led to the same issue. So apparently it's not the iframe itself but perhaps a limitation inside the chromium-engine itself?

Comment: There is a limit to the length of URLs, so the iframe may refuse to load if the URL is too big. Perhaps firefox doesn't enforce the same limit that chrome does. I doubt that kendo has anything to do with this.